# Please help save my dying Areca Palm

Tags: watering, soil, pests

I bought my fully grown Areca palm 1 year ago. It was thriving until suddenly I’ve noticed the leaves are starting to dry out and also noticed brown spots on the stem. Not sure if they have always been there. Changes started after I repotted the Palm using the soil from the garden 3weeks ago. I have since changed the soil entirely to multipurpose compost ( thinking the garden soil was unsuitable as has high clay content ) but the leaves continue to dry. Help save my Palm please![image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Are you able to add a photograph please?

Comment: Please look closely on the underside of the leaves.  Do you see white spots like grains of salt?

Comment: Thankyou for replying. Only under 1-2 leaves and very slight.  Mostly there is nothing on the underside of leaves